# Serializing context on Django CBV?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-serializer

I'm having issues serializing a 3rd party package (django-organizations) as I want to receive the context in JSON.

The class itself looks like this:

```
class OrganizationUserMixin(OrganizationMixin, JSONResponseMixin):
    """Mixin used like a SingleObjectMixin to fetch an organization user"""

    user_model = OrganizationUser
    org_user_context_name = 'organization_user'

    def get_user_model(self):
        return self.user_model

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(OrganizationUserMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        kwargs.update({self.org_user_context_name: self.object,
            self.org_context_name: self.object.organization})
        return kwargs

    def get_object(self):
        """ Returns the OrganizationUser object based on the primary keys for both
        the organization and the organization user.
        """
        if hasattr(self, 'organization_user'):
            return self.organization_user
        organization_pk = self.kwargs.get('organization_pk', None)
        user_pk = self.kwargs.get('user_pk', None)
        self.organization_user = get_object_or_404(
                self.get_user_model().objects.select_related(),
                user__pk=user_pk, organization__pk=organization_pk)
        return self.organization_user
```

And I'm trying to pass this custom JSONResponseMixin to my `OrganizationUserMixin` class:

```
class JSONResponseMixin:
    """
    A mixin that can be used to render a JSON response.
    """
    def render_to_json_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        """
        Returns a JSON response, transforming 'context' to make the payload.
        """
        return JsonResponse(
            self.get_data(context),
            **response_kwargs
        )

    def get_data(self, context):
        print(context)
        return context
```

And then overriding the `render_to_response` in `OrganizationUserMixin` as such:

```
def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
    return self.render_to_json_response(context, **response_kwargs)
```

If I print `context`

It looks something like this

```
# {
# 'object': <OrganizationUser: Erik (MyOrgName)>, 
# 'organizationuser': <OrganizationUser: Erik (MyOrgName)>, 
# 'organization': <Organization: MyOrgName>, 
# 'view': <organizations.views.OrganizationUserDetail object at 0x1091a3ac0>, 
# 'organization_user': <OrganizationUser: Erik (MyOrgName)>
# }
```

The error message I get is `TypeError: Object of type OrganizationUser is not JSON serializable`

How can I serialize the `context` in my JSONResponseMixin?

Comment: What data are you expecting to get out of the serialization? Is it the `__unicode__()` value for the model? then you can check the type of each value in the context dict and if it is an object, replace it with a call of `__unicode__()` on it. That being said, most likely what you need here is to use serializers and define what fields you want to serializer, a generic `JsonResponseMixin` is not enough.

Comment: I wish to get the data in the context to a JSON format,

E.g `'organization_user': <OrganizationUser: Erik (MyOrgName)>` so I can do some AJAX on the page instead of using regular template views

Comment: The `<>` in your comment suggests that this is a python object, you cannot have a python object in Json. 
Do you mean the string `OrganizationUser: Erik (MyOrgName)`?

Comment: Yes, the actual object is what I wish to JSONify

Comment: Ok I understand now, check the answer I just posted and let me know if you have more questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here, either use [Django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) (DRF) or implement functions that performs serialization for the models.

**Option 1**

DRF is a more sustainable solution as you grow the API side of your application, as it would abstract most of de/serialization work, and provide you with alot of other useful functionalities, such as Routers, ViewSets, and other.

**Example Code**

```
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers

class OrganizationUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrganizationUser
        fields = '__all__'


# views.py
from rest_framework import generics

class OrganizationUser(generics.RetrieveModelMixin):
    queryset = OrganizationUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrganizationUserSerializer
```

**Option 2**

That being said, if you the `JsonResponseMixin` is sufficient for most of your needs, and your application is not mainly reliant on the API, you can get away with just adding serialization functions for your models and calling them in your `JsonResponseMixin.get_data()`

**Example code:**

```
# Models.py
class OrganizationUser(models.Model):
    ...

    def to_json(self):
        # assuming you have a field name and organization
        return {"name": self.name, "organization": self.organization.to_json()}

# mixins.py
class JSONResponseMixin:
    """
    A mixin that can be used to render a JSON response.
    """
    def render_to_json_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        """
        Returns a JSON response, transforming 'context' to make the payload.
        """
        return JsonResponse(
            self.get_data(context),
            **response_kwargs
        )

    def get_data(self, context):
        data = {}
        for key, val in context:
            if hasattr(val, "to_json"):
                data[key] = val.to_json()
            else:
                data[key] = val
        return data
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I also think it'll make more sense to incorporate DRF - working with these third party packages is a real rabbit hole. Could you show me how it would look like using DRF?

I tried changing the `get_object()` method in `OrganizationUserMixin` class: https://gist.github.com/erikvlm/c7c1b30f04c22c6a5370b2cf872cd8bf

But I just get a `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'organization'` error.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Do I need to somehow incorporate the APIViews from DRF into my `OrganizationUserMixin` class, or use the `retrieve` method provided by DRF?

Comment: Yes, it might be easiest to just have a different class for the JSON responses, for instance, checkout: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/

Comment: Yeah, I actually got it work that way - thanks for your help. If you wish to modify your answer I'll mark it as completed. I created a new Serializer Class and inherited the basic organization classes

Comment: Happy to help. I updated my answer so you can mark it as complete.